# use .resize() withour loosingthe elements

Tags: c++, matrix, resize, eigen, eigen3

I want to make a dynamic matrix and assign a values specifically to its index so I have to state the size of the matrix before calling the indices, please see the following code

```
void Visual_Servoing::Pose_callback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr &msg)
{   
    
    Rotations.resize(index + 3,3);
    Translations.resize(3, iterator + 1);
    
    std::cout << " #### I'm in Pose_Callback #### " << std::endl;   
    this->hole_detection(frame);
    this->generate_line();
    

    Translation << msg->pose.position.x ,msg->pose.position.y ,msg->pose.position.z;
    Translations.col(iterator) = Translation;
    std::cout << "iterator =" << iterator << std::endl;
    QuatX = msg->pose.orientation.x;
    QuatY = msg->pose.orientation.y;
    QuatZ = msg->pose.orientation.z;
    QuatW = msg->pose.orientation.w;
    Rotation << (1 - (2*pow(QuatY,2)) - (2*pow(QuatZ,2))), (2*QuatX*QuatY + 2*QuatW*QuatZ)   , (2*QuatX*QuatZ - 2*QuatW*QuatY),
                (2*QuatX*QuatY - 2*QuatW*QuatZ)  , (1 - (2*pow(QuatX,2)) - (2*pow(QuatZ,2))) , (2*QuatY*QuatZ + 2*QuatW*QuatX),
                (2*QuatX*QuatZ + 2*QuatW*QuatY)  , (2*QuatY*QuatZ - 2*QuatW*QuatX)   , (1 - (2*pow(QuatX,2)) - (2*pow(QuatY,2)));
    
    Rotations.block(index, 0, 3, 3) = Rotation;
    
    std::cout << Translation << std::endl;  
    std::cout << Translations << std::endl; 
    std::cout << Rotation << std::endl; 
    std::cout << Rotations << std::endl;

    if (iterator>10)
    {   
        Eigen::MatrixXf VectorsCam(3, theta1.size()); // Matrix contains the vectors in camera frame
        VecsinInertial.resize(3, theta1.size());
        CirclePosinFrame();
        
        for (int i=0; i<theta1.size(); i++)
        {
            VecsinInertial.col(i) = Translations.col(i) + Rotations.block(index, 0, 3, 3) * VectorsCam.col(i);  // Each Column represents a vector in inertial frame
        }
        
        VectorCam = Eigen::MatrixXf::Zero(3, 1);
        VectorsCam = Eigen::MatrixXf::Zero(3, theta1.size());
        theta1.clear();
        theta2.clear();
        iterator = 0;
    }
    

    iterator = iterator + 1;
    index = index + 3;
    
    
}
```

How can I update Translations and Rotations matrices sizes without loosing the already existing values in the matrices ? I already assigned Translations and Rotations in the header file as:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf Translations;             // Matrix of Camera Translations Vectors 
Eigen::MatrixXf Rotations;
```

Comment: There is [`conservativeResize`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a712c25be1652e5a64a00f28c8ed11462) -- but you should not use Eigen matrices for dynamically growing objects

Comment: Thanks :D Why do u advise not using Eigen for growing matrices ?

Comment: For example use a `std::vector<Matrix3f>` or `std::vector<Vector3f>`. Or reserve the full size at the beginning (if it is known). You'll need to provide more context for a definitive answer.